# Iterating over objects and changing a value of an object for get-requests doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating over a bunch of select-fields and want to execute a get-request for each of them.
    var selects = { key1 : value }

```
$(".chosen-select-field").each( function ( index ) {
   selects[key2] = $( this ).attr('data-placeholder');
   console.log(selects)
   $.get('filter', selects, function(data){
   }
}
```

All of the attributes which are retrieved form data-placeholder are different but fore some reasons the console.log(selects)-command always shows the same value for key2. It is the one of the last select-field.

The get-request is called as well always with the same values of key2.

Why is that and how can I make it work correctly?

Comment: can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: Does console.log($( this ).attr('data-placeholder')) output different values?

Comment: selects[key2] = $( this ).data('placeholder');

Comment: @ChrisWillard yes it does. Works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is some invalid JS.

I am getting the expected results with the following:

```
var selects = {};

$(".chosen-select-field").each( function ( index ) {
   selects.key2 = $( this ).data('placeholder');
   console.log(selects);
    $.get('filter', selects, function(data){
       console.log(data)
   });
});
```

JSFiddle for testing can be found Here: http://jsfiddle.net/K9pA8/2/

*EDIT:* -- Solved the issue, selects should have been a Object rather than an array (Making assumptions off of the information given)

Comment: for me it outputs 'test2' twice. Chrome 36.

Comment: load the page with the console open